# Android: App runs on emulator but it crashes on my mobile phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash

My app works on the emulator Nexus 5(Android 7.0, API 24) but it crashes on my mobile phone(Samsung J5 Android 5.1.1) in a precise activity when I try to open another activity with an "onClick".

This is the activity which crashes

```
public class CuboActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cubo);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Premi le foto per vederle ingradite oppure visita il menu per vederle una dopo l'altra",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cubo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Per alcune immagini gira il telefono",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FotoCuboActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
            {
                case 1:
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cubo, container, false);
                    return rootView;

                case 2:
                    View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cubo2, container, false);
                    return rootView2;

                case 3:
                    View rootView3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cubo3, container, false);
                    return rootView3;

                case 4:
                    View rootView4 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cubo4, container, false);
                    return rootView4;

                default:
                    View rootView0 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cubo, container, false);
                    return rootView0;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "CONSEGNA";
                case 1:
                    return "LAVORO";
                case 2:
                    return "RISULTATO";
                case 3:
                    return "RELAZIONE";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        switch(arg0.getId())
        {
            case R.id.segaCircolare:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,FragmentCuboActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.lavorazioneCubo:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,FragmentCubo2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
            case R.id.prodottiFiniti:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Gira il telefono",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(this,FragmentCubo3Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                break;
            case R.id.modelloCubo:
                Intent intent4 = new Intent(this,FragmentCubo4Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent4);
                break;
            case R.id.cuboAlto:
                Intent intent5 = new Intent(this,FragmentCubo5Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent5);
                break;
            case R.id.cuboFrontale:
                Intent intent6 = new Intent(this,FragmentCubo6Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent6);
                break;
            case R.id.cuboIntermedio:
                Intent intent7 = new Intent(this,FragmentCubo7Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent7);
                break;
            case R.id.bottoneRelazione:
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J4KJJRzSnY5PSdQYoh6hrTKarl0ID0dtX8TqLga6-dY/edit?usp=sharing");
                Intent intent0 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent0);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the layout of this activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/Procedimento1"
        android:layout_width="321dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/lavorazionecubo"
        android:id="@+id/lavorazioneCubo"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Vuoto"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/Procedimento2"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/modellocubo"
            android:id="@+id/modelloCubo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Vuoto"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/prodottifiniti"
            android:id="@+id/prodottiFiniti"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Vuoto"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is one of the activities which the previous activity doesn't open because it crashes

```
public class FragmentCubo2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_foto_cubo2);
    }
}
```

And this is its layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/lavorazionecubo">
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the logcat

```
12-28 15:46:49.267 2751-2751/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-28 15:46:49.267 2751-2751/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-28 15:46:49.326 2751-2751/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa-2/lib/x86
12-28 15:46:49.332 2751-2751/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa, real application class is null.
12-28 15:46:50.278 2751-2751/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa-2/lib/x86
12-28 15:46:50.546 2751-2751/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-28 15:46:50.793 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-28 15:46:50.793 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
12-28 15:46:50.948 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:46:50.948 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8e7ce4a0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:46:50.998 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:46:50.998 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8e7ce4e0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:49:16.811 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:49:16.811 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8edc9100, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:49:19.918 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:49:19.918 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9ce3cae0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:49:19.993 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:49:19.993 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9b091060, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:49:20.017 2751-2751/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa I/Choreographer: Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-28 15:49:25.376 2751-2751/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa I/Choreographer: Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-28 15:49:26.001 2751-2751/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-28 15:49:26.598 2751-2751/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-28 15:49:29.638 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:49:29.638 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9ce3cac0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:49:32.900 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:49:32.900 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9ce3cae0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:49:34.947 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:49:34.947 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8baf1c00, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:49:35.386 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:49:35.386 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9ce3c380, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:49:38.009 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:49:38.009 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8baf1c00, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:49:40.678 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:49:40.678 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9ce3cae0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-28 15:49:43.712 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa E/EGL_emulation: tid 2780: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-28 15:49:43.713 2751-2780/com.example.utente.progettigscorsipa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8baf1c00, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

Comment: possssst the logggggcatttt , doon't think i sooouund likeee aaa zooombieee

Comment: @PavneetSingh is Logcat eventlog?

Comment: yuuup , [logggcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)

Comment: @PavneetSingh do i post it well?

Comment: @Curio The logs you posted are not what we are looking for. There should be a clear Java exception stack trace at the time the crash occurs. Please edit your post and include that.

Comment: @Karakuri the app crashes in my real mobile phone, not in the emulator. In the emulator it works perfectly

Comment: @Curio then get the logcat from your phone.

Comment: @Karakuri How can I do this?

Comment: @Curio ... the same way you get them from the emulator?

Comment: @Karakuri I create the apk file and it crashes on my mobile. How can I take the logcat from my real mobile phone? Sorry, but I don't understand!

Comment: @Curio It's a lot easier to just plug your phone into your computer and install directly from Android Studio. Then Android Studio would also be able to show you the logcat like it does for the emulator. Alternatively you could [read the tools documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html).

Comment: @Karakuri I solved the problem, it was the low memory of my mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, it was a problem of my mobile, it didn't have enough memory

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android SDK to the version of your android cellphone and in build.gradle file define the minimum and max sdk versions for your mobile.

```
android {
 ...
defaultConfig {
...
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 24
}
productFlavors {
  main {
  ...
 }
 afterLollipop {
   ...
  minSdkVersion 21
}
}
}
```

Comment: @sunnythesine Do I have to change the targetSDKversion to the version of my mobile?

Comment: yes you have to define what is the minimum version your app can run at. As per your post your emulator is Nexus 5(Android 7.0, API 24)  and your phone is (Samsung J5 Android 5.1.1) both have different API versions.

Comment: now it's 15 and I have a mobile 20 sdk, Do I change 15 to 20?

Comment: So minimum should be 15 and maximum should be API level 25 and as per your logcat logs the directory of app is missing when you are running it on cellphone check the permissions and storage space too.

Comment: So do I have to free up space on my mobile phone?

Comment: @sunnytheshine Nothing about the original post suggests it's a problem with the build.gradle configuration. If he were using an incompatible minimum or maximum SDK, the app would not install on the device in the first place.

Comment: @sunnytheshine the problem was the low space of my mobile

Comment: @Curio Ok.. Its better to install mobile usb driver on your computer to directly run your application like you do in Emulator. It will help you to debug your app.